# fetch name of file/image uploaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form which has file upload input

```
<form action="abc.php" method="post">
   <input name="fileToUpload" type="file" />
   <div id="view"></div>
   <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I wish to fetch the name of the file/image uploaded on click of this input and display it under `<div id="view"></div>`, but this needs to be done before the form submission. can anyone please tell how this can be done

Comment: @Saty its just a demo, so have written the data in short

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your code to following,

```
<form action="abc.php" method="post">
   <input name="fileToUpload" id="files" type="file" />
   <div id="view"></div>
   <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
var control = document.getElementById("files");
control.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    // When the control has changed, there are new files
    var i = 0,
        files = control.files,
        len = files.length;
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        document.getElementById('view').innerHTML = files[i].name;
    }

}, false);
</script>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will surely help

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
```

Script Code

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

        // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
        var output = [];
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
          output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                      f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                      f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                      '</li>');
        }
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
      }

      document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```